# Window 8.1 Task Manager startup

Tags: windows-8

Sometimes some programs under Startup are not measured and it is random which are and which are not measured. Sometimes all of them are not measured.

Is it normal? Should all the programs always be measured?

Comment: I have no idea what the question actually means, can you [edit your post](http://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/293604) and try to re-explain so we can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows 8 start up performance timing is not always able to monitor every application. Exactly what constitutes the start up period isn't well defined, so it looks at things like the time taken before CPU and disk use fall to near zero.

If an application decides it needs to do something, e.g. an update, it becomes impossible for Windows to determine how long it spent starting up. This is normal and nothing to worry about.

Comment: THX, that was helpful, in old PC i have Win7 so Win8 feels like alien LOL, not hard to use, but if i look at the processes & other stuff in Task Manger i don't know whats normal & whats not, do i have a small error somewhere without error message or not, do i have something bad on my PC or not despite that i scan with Avast SpyBot & malwarebytes, but some stuff i just can't explain & i think its even pointless to explain if the person to whom I'm explaining to dose not see it, i mean if hes not here & sees it, awry little thing what is different from what i know seems suspicious LOL

Comment: well i am exaggerating a bit, but its almost like i said :D, but u should get the point :)